# Is there any error log file available showing kernel errors while creating sockets in linux?

Tags: c, linux

I have created a TCP client and server program. The TCP client sends a `sync` packet to the server and the server responds to the client with `sync + Ack` packet. After this packed is received by the client, the client network stack itself generated `RST` packet for the flow. I have verified the same with the help of `tcpdump` command. The output shows that the server is not generating any `RST` packet to client. I have searched google to debug further on this but unable to identify any help.

Can any one help me on this to debug further?

Comment: Show some C code if you want real help

Answer (score 0):

Logs are application level handling of how the application is working. It may be error log, console log, access log etc. (Different types of logs for different applications). It does not matter whether kernel issues the error or any other reason, if the application that you are using for creating sockets and handling the connections creates logs, it will be there or else not. 
Also, log files are present in `/var/log` folder in Linux file-system. So, this might help. 
 
PS: I might have given a more specific answer if you would tell what are you using to create sockets and a bit more detail. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Every [socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)-related [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (notably [socket(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html), [connect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html), [bind(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html), [send(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html) etc....) is reporting error condition (e.g. by returning -1 and setting [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) ...). You should systematically check against failure of any [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

As [vish4071 answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32112037/841108) you should also check log files and/or perhaps use [dmesg(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html). And running your program thru [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could also be helpful. Don't forget to compile it with all warnings and debug info (e.g. using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and to use the debugger (`gdb`)

Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).